# Difference between [self view] and self.view?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I've been testing both of them and they seem to work interchangeably, but I'm just curious, is there any real difference between the two or is it just a difference in syntax?

Comment: Please do a search. There have been plenty questions like this (hint: search for dot notation in objective c)

Comment: Sorry, I did try to search, but I didn't know exactly what to search for. Thanks though!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dot notation vs square brackets and casting in Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6292753/dot-notation-vs-square-brackets-and-casting-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dot notation is a shortcut for the getter method of that property. `self.view` will be compiled as `[self view]`.

Comment: Thanks! This question can be removed if necessary.

Comment: Getter or setter actually, depending on the context. :)

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that `[self view]` is a method call, whereas `self.view` is a property access. On most properties, there is no difference.

Answer (score 0):

In Objective-C you can use the dot notation or bracket notation and they are pretty much the same.  I say pretty much..

Please see this thread for more details on subtle differences: [Performance difference between dot notation versus method call in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34674/performance-difference-between-dot-notation-versus-method-call-in-objective-c)